# Erdős–Kac and Poisson

Tags: probabilistic-number-theory

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem) tells us that the Erdős–Kac theorem says that if $\omega$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ then:

> loosely speaking, the probability distribution of $$ \frac{\omega(n) - \log\log n}{\sqrt{\log\log n}} $$ is the standard normal distribution.

and that more precisely

> For any fixed $a<b,$ $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \left ( \frac {1}{x} \cdot \#\left\{ n \leq x : a \le \frac{\omega(n) - \log \log n}{\sqrt{\log \log n}} \le b \right\} \right ) = \Phi(a,b) $$ where $\Phi(a,b)$ is the normal (or "Gaussian") distribution, defined as $$\Phi(a,b)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_a^b e^{-t^2/2} \, dt. $$

So what strikes me is that

- $\omega(n)-1$ is nonnegative-integer-valued, and this same statement should be true of $\omega(n)-1$ as for $\omega(n),$ and
- the expected value is the same as the variance, as it is for the Poisson distribution, and
- if $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ then $\dfrac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt\lambda} \overset{\mathcal L} \longrightarrow \operatorname N(0,1)$ as $\lambda\to\infty,$

so I wonder whether in some reasonable sense we have something here that approaches a Poisson distribution. But which Poisson distribution it is would change as $n$ grows, so I'm not sure how to state the proposition precisely.

So:

- Can this be made precise and proved? and
- All of the cumulants of a Poisson distribution are equal to each other. Are all of the cumulants of $\omega(n)$ asymptotically $\log\log n\text{?}$

Comment: Yes, it is in fact better to think of Erdos-Kac as being Poisson with parameter $\log \log x$ rather than Gaussian.  For example, the tails of the distribution fit into this framework much better.   Look also at the work of Kowalski and Nikeghbali on ``mod Poisson" statistics.

Comment: Mark Kac   wrote a little book Statistical Independence in Probability, Analysis and Number Theory. Chapter 4 is pages 53-79. I don't see a mention of Poisson, but he does the whole business, including the results  for distinct prime factors and prime factors counted with multiplicity. Might be useful.